# Flammability and statistical mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-chemistry

I am wondering to what extent the flammability can be predicted from the statistical properties of an ensemble. Given the partition function of an ensemble, can we in principle predict this property? Is there a chance flammability is a classical property of matter?

Comment: Hydrogen on it's own doesn't burn. It has to be exposed to heat and oxygen in order to burn. You can't look at a single atom when considering chemical reactions except for ionization -- it's the collisions between atoms/molecules that lead to chemical reactions.

Comment: You probably want to construct a system containing not just the flammable substance, but also an added stoichiometric amount of oxygen. Then, figure out whether the entropy is lower when combined or when uncombined (keeping energy constant), that will tell you whether the reaction can proceed spontaneously. Also figure out whether the temperature is higher when combined or uncombined (keeping energy constant), as that will tell you whether the reaction is exothermic or endothermic. This is just a guess though. Not really stat mech but more thermodynamics.

Comment: Sounds interesting though we should keep in mind that many time even highly flammable gases will not burn unless a flame will come close to them (I guess that says something about initial conditions).

Comment: Yep, also I was going to add that flames can be a complex interface phenomenon, much more than predicted by reaction kinetics. For example we know that aluminum likes to burn, even to the point of stealing oxygen from other metal oxides (thermite), however you'd have a hard time lighting a block of aluminum on fire due to the way it passivates its surface, preventing oxygen from penetrating into its bulk.